# Usando glob em Python

Tags: python, soap, glob

Estou montando um client que irá jogar os arquivos encontrados em uma pasta para um WebService SOAP

Esse WebService possui dois métodos que vamos chamar de **MET1** e **MET2**.

- Quando os arquivos encontrados terminarem com .XML e iniciarem com LCL, então eu executo o MET1
- Quando os arquivos encontrados terminarem com .XML e iniciarem com CRC, então eu executo o MET2

Até agora eu fiz da seguinte forma:

```
from zeep import Client
from xml.dom import minidom
import os
import glob


hasha = "9f56ccba6d88d2b089ab8a9fb40dd46f" 


for file in glob.glob('M:\SARA.VEMBU\TRACKING\SINERGIA\\retorno\\*.XML'):
    for file in glob.glob('M:\SARA.VEMBU\TRACKING\SINERGIA\\retorno\\LCL*'):
         arquivo = minidom.parse(file)
         arquivo = arquivo.toxml()
         arquivo = arquivo[22:]  

         client = Client('http://teste.php?wsdl')
         result = client.service.met1(arquivo, hasha)

         print(result.met1Response)

    for file in glob.glob('M:\SARA.VEMBU\TRACKING\SINERGIA\\retorno\\CRC*'):
         arquivo = minidom.parse(file)
         arquivo = arquivo.toxml()
         arquivo = arquivo[22:]  

         client = Client('http://teste.php?wsdl')
         result = client.service.met2(arquivo, hasha)

         print(result.met2Response)
```

Porém o código não retorna nada, mesmo a pasta contendo arquivos com o sufixo e prefixo indicado

obs.: sou iniciante em Python

Comment: Primeiro: por quê você fez um `glob` dentro do outro? O primeiro, que procura por arquivos XML, não tem necessidade de estar aí. Segundo: qual é a sua dúvida? O código está dando algum erro? Qual é a mensagem deste erro? Se não estiver dando erro, está produzindo alguma saída inesperada? Qual seria ela e qual seria a esperada?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sobre o glob: É porque dois filtros são necessários

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Sobre a saida: editei a pergunta

Comment: Você pode unir os filtros em apenas um: `glob.glob(r'M:\\...\\LCL*.xml')`. Desta forma, lista-se todos os arquivos iniciados com LCL e extensão XML. Tente, também, escapar todas as barras invertidas do caminho.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss pra que serve esse r antes do caminho?

Comment: Para definir que a *string* é crua (*raw string*). Isto é, se houver "\n", "\r" ou qualquer caractere semelhante eles não serão escapados. Possivelmente utilizando o "r" no início, nem precise escapar as barras invertidas como falei. Não tenho certeza. Você chegou a testar?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu retirei o r e fiz o escape. Se você quiser pode responder a pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Basta você fazer um `if` pra ver se o arquivo começa com um ou com outro início.

```py
from zeep import Client
from xml.dom import minidom
import os
import glob

hasha = "9f56ccba6d88d2b089ab8a9fb40dd46f" 

for file in glob.glob('M:\SARA.VEMBU\TRACKING\SINERGIA\\retorno\\*.XML'):
    arquivo = minidom.parse(file)
    arquivo = arquivo.toxml()
    arquivo = arquivo[22:]  

    client = Client('http://teste.php?wsdl')

    filename = os.path.filename(file)

    if filename.startswith('LLC'):
        result = client.service.met1(arquivo, hasha)
        print(result.met1Response)
    else if filename.startswith('CRC'):
        result = client.service.met2(arquivo, hasha)
        print(result.met2Response)
```